# org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Crypt leads to Invalid salt value exception

Tags: java, apache-commons

The following code leads to `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` randomly but not always and on one computer, not other used for testing. Reason for the exception is `Invalid salt value: $6$+E3Vebci/+lhkquntg==`. When calling Crypt.crypt() using SHA512 (`$6$`). I can see that the Crypt has a pattern to check against for valid salt: `“^\\$([56])\\$(rounds=(\\d+)\\$)?([\\.\\/a-zA-Z0-9]{1,16}).*“`.

JDK is openjdk 15.0.1 2020-10-20, and commons-codec is version 1.15.

I am just wondering why this happens randomly and on one Windows 10 computer but not on another (macOS Big Sur on M1). And should I then create the salt somehow differently to avoid having this exception? Didn't find anything similar when searching from the internet.

```
byte bytes[] = new byte[13]; 
secureRandom.nextBytes(bytes); // java.security.SecureRandom
String saltBytes = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes));
String salt = "$6$" + saltBytes;
String hashedPassword = Crypt.crypt(user.getPassword(), salt);
```

Stack trace ends at `org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Sha2Crypt.sha2Crypt` at line 181.

PC is MateBook D Intel Core i7-855OU, Windows 10 Home v 1909 build 18363.1379

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [`crypto(String key, String salt)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/Crypt.html#crypt-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

> The exact algorithm depends on the format of the salt string:
>
> - SHA-512 salts start with $6$ and are up to 16 chars long.
>   ...
>   The rest of the salt string is drawn from the set [a-zA-Z0-9./] and is cut at the maximum length of if a "$" sign is encountered.
>   ...
>   **Throws:**
>   IllegalArgumentException - if the salt does not match the allowed pattern

As Base64 encoded string may contains "=", "+", which are not allowed in the regex `[a-zA-Z0-9./]`, you will see error randomly when some invalid character appear in the generated `salt`.

Solutions:

1. Simply use [`crypto(String key)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/Crypt.html#crypt-java.lang.String-) instead as it already provides random salt.
2. Or generate salt following the allowed pattern.

Reference:
[rfc4648 - Table 1: The Base 64 Alphabet](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt)

Comment: Good suggestion. The reason why the salt was generated "manually" is not valid anymore, so could as well use the crypt(String key) now.

Comment: I don't have a mac now. It is interesting that mac can't reproduce the problem. How many times did you try in mac?

Comment: Though the docs also say: A salt is generated for you using ThreadLocalRandom; for more secure salts consider using SecureRandom to generate your own salts and calling crypt(String, String).

Comment: I have a server doing the password hashing that I test with a client running 1500 test cases, I run the tests in four terminals for about ten times and didn't get the issue even once. Not all test cases obviously result in password hashing but many do.

Comment: Java's `Base64.getUrlEncoder()` uses the 'url-safe' alphabet and if you applied it to a 12-byte value (not 13) you'd get 16 good chars every time. That said, I agree it's easier to let the library do it for you.